# How do we distinguish Wikipedia categories as sets and topics?

Tags: mediawiki, categories, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

Wikipedia categories are primarily of two types: Set categories (like Category:Philosophers in France) and Topic categories (Like Category:France). I can query wiki api using the following url:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=categories&titles=Barack%20Obama&cldir=descending&clshow=!hidden&cllimit=max&format=xml

I want to retrieve only topic categories, not the set categories. I have browsed extensively through the api and I have not been able to find how to apply this filter / specify the property requirements. How can I do this?

Comment: I don't believe categories are marked as sets or topics in any machine-readable way.

Answer (score 3):

I can't comment, so I'll answer: *You can't*.

Mediawiki categories don't have types, they are a "tag" you apply to pages. They can be nested into each other and so create hierarchies (which eventually do tangle with each other, creating fuzzy classifications).
All policies for creation of Categories are written by humans for humans (and are rarely complied with, depending on the WikiProject).